# How to change the X-axis label format in a Power BI continuous line chart to show the first month of each quarter instead of each semester

Tags: datetime, graph, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm trying to create a line chart in Power BI with the X-axis showing continuous daily results, but with the X-axis label showing only the first month of each quarter.

By default, Power BI uses a semester based X-axis label.

I have tried changing the data type of the X-axis column.
Also tried using a categorical axis, but it shows the values sums the data, instead of showing the daily results. Hierarchic data also shows aggregated data.

I am not sure how to make the axis labels show the first month of each quarter. Can anyone help?

**Additional information:**

Version: 2.112.1421.0 64-bit (january 2023)

Data = `Hist_VaR`
Time variable = `DT_REF`
Y-axis = `VaR`

Thank you for your time!